# Reverse order of bits (like Long.reverse())

Tags: kotlin

I have a `Long` and want to reverse the order of the bits. I can call [`java.lang.Long.reverse(myLong)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#reverse-long-), but is there a Kotlin builtin to accomplish the same thing? The closest I can find is [`BitSet.flip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native/-bit-set/flip.html)

Comment: do you need it for kotlin native? otherwise using the java libs is fine.

Comment: I don't, the necessary call to Java seems odd is all. Verbose if nothing else.

Comment: I've made a ticket for that - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-51721

Answer (score 0):

If using the full java path seems verbose, one way would be to create an extension function.

```
fun Long.myReverse() = java.lang.Long.reverse(this)
```

And this would be called like this:

```
myLong.myReverse()
```

Since kotlin doesn't actually use the java `.reverse()` you could probably name it that directly, but I would avoid that in case they add it in the future.